# Early AppsFlyer network request before calling start()

Tags: android, analytics, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I upgraded from AppsFlyer 6.3.2 to 6.12.3 and noticed that after the first installation, the network request for updating the config (`cdn-settings.appsflyersdk.com`) was sent before the `AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().start(context)` call (previously, requests started [only after it](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001422989-User-opt-in-opt-out-in-the-AppsFlyer-SDK#optout-at-installation)). Calling `updateServerUninstallToken` also triggers another request (`register.appsflyersdk.com`), I can delay this call myself, but not the first one. No library in my project makes network requests while we are waiting for consent from the user. There were no problems before, how to avoid them now? I created the [issue](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-android-sdk/issues/62) on GitHub, but they seem to have stopped answering there

[image]